# range.set_Value formatting for dates in Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto

The following code puts date values into excel, but for some reason they are not automatically formatted as date. If I enter these dates manually – they get formatted automatically. Excel is running on Windows with European locale setting. How do I make Excel format the dates automatically? I can't explicitly apply formatting as the range I'm putting into excel may contain columns of different data types and the whole range has to be inserted in one shot for performance reasons.

```
string[,] arr = new string [2, 2];
            arr[0, 0] = "Date";
            arr[0, 1] = "DateTime";
            arr[1, 0] = "21/12/2018";
            arr[1, 1] = "26/12/2019";
            Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Range["A1:B2"];
            rng.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, arr);
```

UPDATE:
I've actually narrowed it down to the following:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat); 
worksheet.Range["A1"].Value = dt;
```

It's bizarre, the string is formatted according to the user's locale setting, but when I insert it into excel in the second line – Excel for some reason converts it to US format. So with european date format setup in Windows, if the string is "11/03/2019", what I see in Excel after I run the code is "03/11/2019".

Comment: You can use the method `Range.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"` to format the value as a date.

Comment: I can't format the date with any specific format as it comes through differently for different users (in different countries). The data already arrives formatted as date, my issue is that Excel for some reason doesn't recognize it as a date when doing range.set_Value. If I double-click into the cell with the inserted date value and hit enter – it recognizes it fine. Just wondering if there's a way to make excel recognize dates when setting the range value.